# Deleting entries from table based on count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with users. It contains a row called uplink. i need help with deleting users based on their points. the uplink table is updated when each time the user gain a point. the uplink table writes the username in it with auto increment id row. i can see the points of the user by executing
the following commands.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM media WHERE username='username'
```

i need to delete the users who have point less than 1

i want to do something like

```
DELETE FROM media WHERE uplink HAVING COUNT(*) < 1
```

Need a solution

I am trying on a linux server with phpmyadmin installed. the table name was media.

Comment: I am totally confused.  For instance, s `uplink` a table or a column?  Why would the sample code having `count(*) < 1` -- that would imply that there are no rows.  A clear statement of the problem, sample data, and desired results all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the users which have less than 1 point:

```
SELECT username
FROM media
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(username) < 1;
```

Delete the users using the query above

```
DELETE FROM media
WHERE username IN (
    SELECT username
    FROM media
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING COUNT(username) < 1;
)
```

Comment: executed successfully